# Send progress on button pressed instead slider change

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter game template to create a test, where if user clicks on specific button, it register the right answer and forward the user to the screen with the score and congratulations.
For now, when I change slider to button, I face this issue in main.dart:
[image]

My code for play session screen

```
                        Consumer<LevelState>(
                  builder: (context, levelState, child) =>
                  FilledButton(
                    onPressed: ()  =>
                    GoRouter.of(context).go('/play/won'),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                  if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return Color(0xFF55A318);
                  return  Color(0XFFE4DBC8);
                 }, 
                 ),
            ),
                    
                    child: Text('Ostrich bias ${widget.level.difficulty}', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000))),
            ),
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtTtn.png)

Slider part

```
    Text('Drag the slider to ${widget.level.difficulty}%'
                    ' or above!'),
                Consumer<LevelState>(
                  builder: (context, levelState, child) => Slider(
                    label: 'Level Progress',
                    autofocus: true,
                    value: levelState.progress / 100,
                    onChanged: (value) =>
                        levelState.setProgress((value * 100).round()),
                    onChangeEnd: (value) => levelState.evaluate(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Inside the `GoRoute` definition for the `/won` page, you attempt to access the `extra` parameter:

`final map = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic`.

However, note that in one of your buttons, you navigate to that route **without** providing an `extra` parameter. The line in question is:

`GoRouter.of(context).go('/play/won')`

When `GoRouter` navigates to the page, and attempts to access the `extra` parameter, you will receive a crash because you are attempting to cast a non-existent (AKA `null`) value to a map (**1.**).

**2.** Solution:

You will have to implement logic for handling a non-existent value in your `GoRoute` definition. In your scenario, you can first check if the cast *can* succeed:

`if (state.extra is Map<String, dynamic) { /*handle missing score, etc.*/ }`

Another approach would be to validate that the user can only go to the `/won` page if they have the data that you need (a score, etc.).

In general terms:

```
FilledButton(
  onPressed: () {
    /// Verify that the player conditions for winning the game as valid.
    if (player.hasScore) {
      /// Only then, can we navigate to the win page.
      GoRouter.of(context).go('/play/won', extra: {"score": score});
      ///                                  ^^^^^ always pass this.
    }
  },
  ...
)
```